# How to temporary delete some rows in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SP I want to delete some rows from a Table and after some code insert the deleted rows in the same table. 
How can I do it?

Thanks all.

**Update:**

I have a Table:

SampleTable(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)

I want to do that:

```
DELETE FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Col1 = "foo"

-- SOME CODE...

INSERT INTO SampleTable 
[DELETED VALUES...]
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry but now I can't see the DB.

The problem is that in the `SOME CODE...` part, written by others, there is a delete that give me an error, but after the delete there is an insert with the SP input that replaced the deleted row with the same key.

I know that an UPDATE apparently solve my problem but there is a lot of logic and I don't want to change the `SOME CODE...` part, so I'm looking for a workaround, and so I want to *temporary* ignore foreign key

Comment: will you explain breafly what you actually want to do?

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? In the deletion part? In the insertion part? In the part where you execute code between deletion and insertion?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Why not flag the relevant rows, and just filter them out in the code code in between, and then update the flag after your code. For a better answer you need to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: And what about a soft delete? Add a "deleted" column. Update your rows with deleted=true, execute your code and then update again with deleted=false.

Comment: I need to delete the rows because I don't want problems with foreign key when I operate on others tables.

Comment: What kind of problem don't you want?  Most of the time, a foreign key is required to _exist_, so this seems backwards.  What is the exact situation you're trying to deal with?  Can you give us a sample db and situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and re-inserting the rows can introduce all sorts of problems.  For instance, `identity()` values will change (as well as automatically assigned creation times).  In addition, you might have  constraints.  In theory, anything could happen to the database between the deletion and re-insertion, so constraints that once worked might fail.

How about creating a view?

```
create view v_SampleTable as
    select *
    from SampleTable
    where col1 = 'foo' or col1 is null;
```

Then change the code to use `v_SampleTable` instead of `SampleTable`.  This is an updatable view, so it will even permit modifications to the data inside the table.

You could go even one step further and rename the table first and then create a view with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

select * into #ttable FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Col1 = "foo"

DELETE FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Col1 = "foo"

-- SOME CODE...

INSERT INTO SampleTable 
select * from #ttable

Comment: #ttable is a temporary table? I need to create it before use it? It works with all data types?

Comment: Note that the simple problem with this answer is that you have to lock the _entire_ table for the paired insert-to-temp and delete, or you run the risk of a row going missing.  The big problem of course is that, because it's a temp table, it probably won't survive the db going down.  Tables can usually be created as the result of a `SELECT` statement, so creation isn't a problem, but recovery is (or multi-threading, if you try to make it a permanent table).

Comment: I'm looking for a workaround to ignore temporary foreign key (see update), do you know a more secure method?